# Transpose Excel Table Horizontally, but also multiply the number of rows for the first column?

Tags: excel, transform, etl, transpose

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I was unable to find anything specific to this need, probably due to it being odd to phrase. Essentially I have a table like this that I would like to transform into the table below:

| zip | blue | green |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1 | 2 |

| zip | color |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | blue |
| 10000 | green |

Ideally, I would like to do this all purely in SQL or purely in Excel, but eventually I will want to transpose through R or Python once I get more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+, and Excel 365.

- Select some single cell in your source table
- `Data => Get Data => from within sheet`
- In the PQ UI, select the `Zip` column
- `Transform => Unpivot => Unpivot other columns`
- Delete the `Values` column
- Rename the `Attribute Column => Color`
- `Home => Close & Load`

Here is M-Code that will do the same thing, with some changes so as not to have to hard-code other colors that you might have besides the two you show.

You would paste this into the Advanced Editor of PQ; change the Table name at the top.  Then read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm.

```
let

//Change table name in next line to the actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],

//set data types
//   Zip is text to retain leading zero's
//   Others are all integers
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"zip", type text}} & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1), each {_, Int64.Type})),

//Unpivot all columns except for the Zip column
//   And name the "color" column as "Color"
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"zip"}, "Color", "Value"),

//Remove the value column since you do not show it in your result example
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Value"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]